# Codename one bug- Every time i upload gif image, i am unable to pick new images from .res file

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to upload a new animation for splash. I am creating the animation in theme.res file.
I have tried both through "add animation", to add a gif file, and "add new", to create the animation myself.

However, every time i do this process, and i go to the new GUI builder, when i press "pick an image from res file", nothing happens, and I am unable to pick a new image. 
This happens **every time** i add a new animation to the .res file. I am unable to add it without the program getting this bug.

I have gone to previous versions, but i cannot make the animation work due to this bug. How can i fix it?

[image: pick image]
[image: pick animation]

Answer (score 0):

These old style animations aren't supported in the new GUI builder. They are very inefficient and large.

The best alternative is to place the gif in the filesystem and load it using the gif cn1lib into a label you placed using the GUI builder. You will need to handcode the loading portion as it uses the animated gif cn1lib: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/animated-gif-support.html